# How do I get real-time update on my online IDE and VSCode app with files on my github repo?

Tags: html, git, github, web, repo

I am coding on an online IDE connected to a github repo. This same github repo is what i use on vscode. I tried using git status and git log to see if whatever commits and pushes I have made on the former would appear in vscode but it did not.
I want the files that I commit and push onto my repo to appear on either IDEs. What do i do?